# file_get_contents() doesn't return FQL results even if the fql itself in url works

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-fql, file-get-contents

Type this query in url bar, it works. I can get the results on the browser window.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+actor_id+FROM+stream+WHERE+post_id+IN+(SELECT+post_id+FROM+stream+WHERE+filter_key+in+(SELECT+filter_key+FROM+stream_filter+WHERE+uid=me()+AND+name='Links')+AND+attachment.caption+in+('xxxx.com','xxxx.com')+AND+type=80+AND+created_time%3C=now()+LIMIT+20)+ORDER+BY+created_time+DESC+&access_token=xxxx...
```

But php code below doesn't. file_get_contents() returns empty array.

```
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
        . 'fql?q=' . str_replace(' ', '+', $query1)
        . '&access_token=' . $access_token;
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
```

The query mentioned above is dump of $fql_query_url.

App already has got permissions below.

- read_stream
- read_insights

Does anyone know anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by myself.

```
attachment.caption in xxxx
```

was the cause of no results regardless of that **it works when you type query in url bar**.